# Easiest way to get subclips of youtube videos, to upload elsewhere

Tags: youtube

Looking for a way (read software or software pipeline) to quickly snip bits of youtube videos for upload or video montage.
Is there such software?

Manual way would to be to download and use the video in a video editor.

I'm looking for something quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with any copyright issues is, of course, your own problem but *assuming you have taken care of such issues*:

The [Python](https://python.org) libraries:

- [youtube-dl](https://youtube-dl.org/) - Can download videos from a number of sources
- [MoviePy](https://pypi.org/project/moviepy/) - Can easily extract sections of videos and combine them into a sequence or montage. *Note that MoviePy installs and uses FFMPEG as a back-end*

All of the above tools are free, gratis, open source and available for multiple platforms.
If you are regularly doing the same process you can script the process.